# How to create a new record from django query set

Tags: python, django, orm

I have heard of a django orm hack somewhere. It goes like this

```
dp = SomeModel.objects.filter(type="customer").last()
dp.id = dp.id + 1 #changing id to a new one
dp.save()
```

The last step supposedly creates a new record provided the value of id being used doesn't exist. In case the incremented id exists, then the save method acts like the update method.
example ::

```
dp.version += 1 #updating some random field
dp.save() # will change the newer version of dp.id
```

I would like to ask veterans in django two questions for our benefit,

1. Is there a sure shot way of creating a new record from an old record with the latest auto_increment_pk instead of pk + 1 method
2. Is the above method any faster or better. One advantage I see is if I have a model with 10 fields and I want to create a new record from an old one with only 1 or 2 changes from the older one, this method saves 8 lines of code.

Thank You

Comment: As both answers say, using `None` is preferred to using `+1`. With `+1` it's possible to overwrite an existing row, either because of a race condition, because the initial queryset might not be ordered by pk, or because the model might use a different primary key scheme from the default.

Answer (score 4):

`last()` returns the last instance with regard to the ordering of the according `QuerySet`. This instance is not guaranteed to have the biggest pk in use. And if it did, there would be no guarantee that no other instance is created between retrieving the old highest pk and committing the new instance with `pk + 1`. Such an instance would be overwritten by the new clone. Hence, do not manually set a new pk, but let the data base handle that. As others have suggested, that is easily done by setting the pk to `None`:

```
instance.pk = None
instance.save()
```

Comment: Accepted. The other way is to do a filter for all. then order by id in descending order. But the caveat is that we should do all this in a transaction....which is bad practice at least here. Thanks for the detailed explanation.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, Make `id` as None.

```
dp = SomeModel.objects.filter(type="customer").last()
dp.id = None
dp.save()
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I checked and it worked perfectly. Marking yours as the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than incrementing the pk, you should set it to None. Then it will always be saved as a new record.

Comment: both have given the right answer. But since @itzMEonTV gave the code, I accept his answer. I have up voted your answer though. Thank you very much.